# Browser printing binary data with a HTTP header in the middle

Tags: php, apache

The last 2-3 days some of our users have been reporting this error.  Random pages on our site will output raw binary data.  None of the developers can duplicate the issue which comes and goes randomly.

<del>All users reporting the issue have so far been using IE11.</del> The server is Apache 2.4.16 with PHP 5.3.29. There are NO errors being logged by PHP or by Apache related to the issue.

Oddly the HTTP header is embedded in the middle of the data. I can't even fathom a reason that would ever happen.  One would expect that if the browser was having issues rendering the content, then it wouldn't be making further requests for more resources to the server and there wouldn't be another HTTP header to show.

We really don't know where to start with this one, we can't tell if it's server, php code, or browser related.  Is anyone aware of bugs in Apache <del>or IE</del> that would cause this?

Attached is a screenshot one of the users sent.

[image]

Comment: wireshark can be your friend.

Comment: Thanks @DanielA.White, but like I said we couldn't replicate the problem on any of the developers machines. Once we finally did, a Chrome code inspector network capture did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug. The PHP code was generating a 302 redirect, but then also outputting it's normal page content. In certain high load conditions outputting the page could take 3-5 seconds. For some still undetermined reason the output from the first (redirected) request was being munged onto the beginning of the new request before that request's headers, turning the entire thing into garbage.

If anyone knows why THAT behavior - the content of one terminated request being prepended onto a new active request - is happening feel free to answer the question so I can fully mark it solved.

Comment: it could be http keep alive.